# Django: Multiple Content-Type: text/html appears on html page

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, render-to-response

I'm working on a Django project that accesses different tables from my database and outputting that information all on one page. The way I'm doing that is:

```
a = get_hostname(request, hostname)
b = get_systeam(request, hostname)
c = get_appteam(request, hostname)

response = HttpResponse()
response.write(a)
response.write(b)
response.write(c)
return HttpResponse(response)
```

Where all the called functions return HTTPresponse objects through render_to_response methods. When I use Javascript to see the concatenated html, there are multiple Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8 that appear on the page.

```
<h2>
    <div class ="row">
    <center>
      <div class ="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
        <h1>Hostname: xxxxxxx </h1>
      </div>
</h2>
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8



<h3>

    <div class ="row">

      <div class ="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1>System Team: xxxxxx </h1>
      </div>

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8


      <div class = "col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">

        <h1>Application Team: xxxxxxxx </h1>
      </div>


    </div>
</h3>
```

I have a feeling the meta tag in what is my base.html isn't being passed so when the html chunks are being rendered they automatically add the Content-Type lines. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your desired behavior?

Comment: Trying to access different tables within my database and display the information retrieved in a specific html format (using Bootstrap). However, extra Content-Type lines are being outputted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with meta tags.

You should only create one HttpResponse. Your functions should not use render_to_response, they should either use render_to_string or just directly render their contents and return them.

Also, in your function `response` is already an HttpResponse, so you should just return it at the end rather than wrapping it in yet another HttpResponse.

Comment: Thanks!This worked.I originally used get_template and render and I absent-mindedly forgot to delete the HttpResponse.